# Gibt es ein deutsches Pendant zur englischen Wendung «writ large»?

Tags: word-choice, english-to-german, phrase, vocabulary

In der englischen Sprache gibt es die Wendung «writ large», die normalerweise so benutzt wird:

> Switzerland is a democracy writ large.

oder

> The State is the organization of robbery writ large.

Nämlich, dass A wie B ist, aber auf einer überspitzteren oder stärkeren Art.

Gibt es ein deutsches Pendant ähnlich zu «writ large»? Wie würdet Ihr die obengenannten Sätze ins Deutsche übersetzen?

Comment: Ihr könnt natürlich mein Deutsch korrigieren; ich bin kein Muttersprachler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Möglich (zumindest bei den beiden gegebenen Beispielen) wäre auch *par excellence*.

Comment: Sehr gute Idee. Gefällt mir. Bei *par excellence* kommt mir dann noch *schlechthin* in den Sinn. Ich frage mich nur gerade, ob *writ large* und *par excellence* im Englischen synonym verwendet werden kann.

Comment: Oh, *schlechthin* ist auch schön! Und auch nicht französisch, so dass man nicht erst die Schreibung googeln muss :-D Wobei bei *schlechthin* eigentlich kein unbestimmter Artikel stehen würde, oder? Sondern beispielsweise *Die Schweiz ist DIE Demokratie schlechthin*.

Comment: Ja. In dem Satz würde man den bestimmten Artiekl mit *schlechthin* verwenden. Anders aber glaube ich: *Die Schweiz entwickelte sich zu einer Demokratie schlechthin.* Passt das?

Comment: Weiß nicht genau - klingt für mich irgendwie seltsam. Gefühlt so ein bisschen wie *Volkswagen - DAS Auto* gegen *Volkswagen - ein Auto*. Also ich würde *schlechthin* immer mit betontem bestimmtem Artikel verwenden. Aber begründen oder beweisen kann ich's nicht.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Hmm… geht _par excellence_ auch, wenn der Satz eine negative Bedeutung hat? _Der Staat ist das Verbrechen par excellence_ klingt ein bisschen komisch.

Comment: Ich glaube schon, dass das geht, wenn die *Bedeutung* negativ ist. Aber ich bin mir nicht sicher, was wäre, wenn der Satz wirklich negiert ist, zum Beispiel: *Switzerland is not a democracy writ large*...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Danke. Was denkst Du über die Antwort oben, _… in Reinkultur_?

Comment: @TheHumbleShaver: Das oben finde ich auch gut - es kommt immer ein bisschen auf den "Unterton" an, den man ausdrücken möchte. Das ist aber schwierig zu erklären oder zu definieren. *Verstanden* wird es aber auf jeden Fall richtig. Auch das mit *schlechthin* von EM1 ist gut.

Answer (score 14):

Mein Vorschlag: *in Reinkultur*:

> Die Schweiz ist Demokratie in Reinkultur
>
> Der Staat ist Raubrittertum in Reinkultur

Answer (score 0):

Ein weiterer Ausdruck wäre "lupenrein". Aber dank Gerhard Schröder ist dieser Begriff inzwischen etwas vorbelastet. Insbesondere in Verbindung mit Demokratie oder Demokraten würde ich ihn derzeit allenfalls ironisch verwenden.