# Kann "schlechthin" auch mit unbestimmtem Artikel stehen?

Tags: usage, definite-article

In einer Kommentardiskussion zu einer anderen Frage hat sich eine weitere interessante Fragestellung ergeben, nämlich ob *schlechthin* immer mit betontem bestimmtem Artikel steht oder auch mit unbestimmtem Artikel stehen kann.

Ich habe es bisher immer so gesehen, dass *schlechthin*  immer mit bestimmtem Artikel stehen muss, weil man ja ein bestimmtes Subjekt als **das** Beispiel (im Sinne von: das Paradebeispiel) für eine Eigenschaft heraushebt.

Beispiele (Fettschrift hier im Sinne von "besonders betont ausgesprochen"):

> Eric Clapton ist **der** Gitarrist schlechthin.
>   Griechenland ist **das** Urlaubsland schlechthin.

Wäre es auch möglich zu sagen:

> Griechenland ist **ein** Urlaubsland schlechthin.

Für mich klingt das sehr seltsam - etwa so, als hätte der Volkswagen-Konzern den Werbeslogan: "Volkswagen - **ein** Auto".

Comment: In deinem *Griechenland-Beispiel* ist der unbestimmte Artikel falsch. Das Beispiel, was ich angeführt hatte, war *etwas* anders: *Griechenland entwickelte sich zu einem Urlaubsland schlechthin.* Hier modifiziert *schlechthin* den Prozess, konkret die Vollendung der Entwicklung. Die Frage lautet also eher kann *schlechthin* einen Prozess beschreiben, oder nur *das Endstadium*.

Comment: Könntest Du die andere Frage verlinken?

Comment: @Em1: Hm, wenn in Deinem Beispiel *schlechthin* den Prozess beschreiben würde, müsste der Satz dann nicht heißen *Griechenland entwickelte sich schlechthin zu einem Urlaubsland*?

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald: Ja :-) http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5451/gibt-es-ein-deutsches-pendant-zur-englischen-wendung-writ-large/5454#5454

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Ja, das ist so was mit dem Adverb. Das ist an beiden Stellen richtig. *Der Mann fuhr vorsichtig das Auto* und *Der Mann fuhr das Auto vorsichtig* sind beide grammatikalisch richtig und bedeuten dasselbe. Das *schlechthin* kann hier seine Position auch variieren, aber ich gebe dir recht, dass es eindeutiger ist, wenn es nicht am Ende steht.

Comment: Kann es sein, dass Du statt *schlechthin* *schlichtweg* meinst? Denn in der Form *... entwickelte sich schlechthin ...* hab ich's auch noch nie gehört. *schlichtweg* kann man übrigens meines Erachtens nach nicht hinten anstellen, wie in *Griechenland entwickelte sich schlichtweg zu dem Urlaubsland schlechthin* :-)

Comment: Außerdem funktioniert das mit dem Umstellen des Adverbs nur bei bestimmtem Objekt. Man kann nicht sagen *Der Mann fuhr Auto vorsichtig*. Sehr wohl aber kann man sagen *Der Mann fuhr vorsichtig Auto*.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Die beiden Wörter sind so ähnlich und doch so verschieden. Ich hab gerade keinen klaren Kopf mehr darüber. - Ich weiß nicht, ob du die Notification bekommen hast, aber ich hab im Chat noch was zu dem Thema geschrieben.

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde sagen, das ist möglich, obwohl ich den Satz so auch noch nie gehört habe.

"Schlechthin" bedeutet, wenn es einem Substantiv nachgestellt wird,

> an sich, im eigentlichen Sinn, in Reinkultur, par excellence, per se, ohne Einschränkung

siehe [hier](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/schlechthin)

Dein Satz würde in anderer Form etwa lauten

> Griechenland ist ein Urlaubsland par excellence/in Reinkultur.

Die Verwendung von "schlechthin" in Zusammenhang mit dem bestimmten Artikel ist sicherlich häufiger, schließt aber m.E. diejenige des unbestimmten Artikels nicht aus. Siehe z.B. diese Bildung

> Beschreibung eines Urlaubslandes schlechthin

Bedeutung hier "an sich"

Comment: Ja, mit *par excellence* und *in Reinkultur* stimme ich dir zu, aber *schlechthin* schreit für mich nach dem bestimmten Artikel, weil der ja auch beim Sprechen des Satzes besonders betont wird.

Comment: *schlechthin* hat imho eine andere Konnotation als *par excellence* oder *in Reinkultur*. Es stellt das Ausgesagte als das *Ultimative* dar. Quasi: Es gibt nichts besseres, höheres, stärkeres, extremeres, und wohl auch nichts Gleichgestelltes ... Die anderen vermitteln mir, dass es daneben auch noch andere gibt, die gleichwertig sind.

Comment: Genau! Und deswegen finde ich ja, dass es mit unbestimmtem Artikel auch nicht geht (weder als Prozess, noch als Ergebnis des Prozesses).